# nginx hanging for subdomain

Tags: php, nginx

I'm having some trouble getting nginx to work on a subdomain. I have two `conf` files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` as follows (some details in the first redacted):

`mydomain.conf`: the site proper, `server_name` of `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com`:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    root            /var/www/sites/mydomain;
    index           index.php;
    server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/mydomain.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/mydomain.error.log;

    ...
}
```

`phpmyadmin.conf`:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    root            /var/www/sites/phpmyadmin;
    index           index.php;
    server_name     pma.mydomain.com;

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin.error.log;

    location / {
            index index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            try_files       $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Currently, `/var/www/sites/phpmyadmin` just contains an `index.php` with `<?php phpinfo(): ?>` in it and nothing else. This is on an EC2 instance and I'm trying to load the pages from another computer, wherein both `mydomain.com` and `pma.mydomain.com` are set to its IP address in my `/etc/hosts`.

Navigating to `mydomain.com` works perfectly fine, PHP works, etc. However when I navigate to the subdomain, it hangs. For any other subdomain the connection immediately fails (there are no DNS records). But for `pma` it simply doesn't load.

My log files for `pma` are empty and unhelpful. I have no idea how to debug this silent failure and it's driving me insane.

Comment: I found the problem. The issue was rather with hosts configuration client side. So, issue seems to be resolved. I was looking in the wrong place. Kudos to Cody Caughlan for helping me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably an issue with the FastCGI handler (are you using `php-fpm`?) running at `127.0.0.1:9000` - is it running and accepting connections?

Debug it by SSHing to that machine and running:

`curl -vv http://127.0.0.1:9000/`

What happens?

Comment: I am indeed using php-fpm (PHP 5.4 x86_64 specifically). When I curl `localhost:9000` the result is `Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`. HOWEVER, it's worth nothing that for the main domain I have an `info.php` file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it that's working.

Moreover navigating to it at the moment gives me the Magento setup page (which is PHP)...

Comment: Look at the `php-fpm` config at http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File  and see if you can crank up the log level / verbosity and see if fpm gives anything useful. Also - ensure that you don't have any firewall rules in place that are blocking port 9000.

Comment: `php-fpm` is working perfectly on the main domain. I checked all the php-fpm logs, and there's nothing there except startups and terminations. Port 9000 is blocked externally but available and handling FCGI requests locally.

Comment: Please see my comment on the main post. Thanks for your help!